# Are "Bonus Questions" considered an ok request?

Tags: discussion

What is the community's stance, as a rule, regarding "Bonus" or "Follow-up" questions?

To be clear, I am defining such a question like so:

- It is a follow-up or related question asked after the primary question is stated but is rather simple and straight-forward to answer.
- Context makes it clear that answering the second question is not required for receiving the answer mark.
- The answer to the additional question provides either further clarity or "flavor" on the subject but isn't required to fully understand the primary question.

With the above outlined conditions, what are the thoughts of the community and asking secondary "bonus" questions within questions?  Personally, I like throwing out these additional questions because they aren't required and with a few extra keystrokes, the answerer might be able to provide a little extra clarity.

Comment: What's wrong with separate questions? You can always refer to other questions you've asked previously if you think it will provide additional context.

Comment: @RobertLongson Consider it a "simple" question, and rather than drafting another question, settting up, potentially, the exact same context and then asking again, you just ask it in the same post.  If the question becomes important, and isn't addressed, yes you can ask another one.  However, if it's easy to ask and easy to answer, why not request the additional details?  I guess that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: Personal opinion: I don't like "bonus" questions. My gut instinct says they're "too broad." A question should be just that: **a** question. That being said, I'll usually answer these if the bonus question is small enough.

Comment: If it's the same details it won't take you long to set up now will it. And just because you think the followup is simple doesn't mean that you're right.

Comment: @MikeC, this is why I require them to not be a requirement to answering the official question.  Regardless, even if you (and others) don't prefer them, does that mean they make the entire question off-topic and should have it flagged for closure or edit OR does that mean you may not prefer it but it is still acceptable practice?

Comment: A much *much* bigger problem in my experience is people asking a question, that is clearly and fully answered, and then asking a followup question *on a different topic* by editing their original question or asking in comments. Think someone asking about how to make an Ajax query, and then following up with a question about an SQL statement. The two are only related because the OP is facing both problems in the context of working on the same project but are otherwise two different questions.

Comment: @Louis, yes, I would consider that an abuse of Edit privileges.

Comment: @RLH In my experience, I'll flag it as off-topic if I think the "bonus" question requires more than a couple of sentences to a paragraph to answer. I don't like the idea of writing two *complete* answers on a single question, you know?

Comment: I'd like to see some examples.  For me, it's okay to have multiple question marks in the question, but only if they are all aspects of the same issue - so it's more of a single question with multiple question marks than multiple questions.  In that sense it's acceptable only if all the question marks should be answered to get a complete answer.  If it's really an additional question, my preference is for it to be asked as a separate question.

Comment: This is is no way asking about the same situation as the "duplicate". There the protagonist was leaving comments nagging the answerer to look at other related questions as far as I can see.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily call them "bonus" questions, but the concept you describe is the suggested way of doing things here. Just make sure *not* to edit in "secondary "bonus" questions within [the] question".

If you ask a question and realize that there is a related issue then do not modify your question or ask an answerer to expand indefinitely in their answer. Post a separate question with the related issue - just make sure that it is not somehow required to know about the other question in order to answer it.

You may link back to the other question, but it shouldn't be required - if it is then consider editing the question to stand on its own. You may direct the answerer to your related question, but it shouldn't be required - if it is then edit the question to appeal to any user answering.

tl;dr; Nothing wrong with posting another question, it is encouraged. Just make sure that it follows the same criteria as any other question being posted on Stack Overflow, and hopefully also contains a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You seem to interpret 'bonus question' as a separate question, how I read it, is as a secondary question within the primary question.

Comment: `I wouldn't necessarily call them "bonus" questions` but neophyte users do which is what I think the OP is referring to.  They will also refer to them using *for bonus points, how do I....*

Answer (score 14):

Well I can't speak to a community-accepted standard, this is my opinion of what would be best practice...

- **Changing topics (bad):** If the "bonus" question is on a different topic altogether it definitely should not be asked. This doesn't even meet your criteria of what you considered a bonus question
- **Call to improve answers (good):** If the effective result of the bonus question(s) caused question answserers to modify/update their answered to provide more clarity *(as stated in your 3rd bullet)* and overall better answers to the question, then **it should be asked**. That may be tough to determine as you're drafting your bonus question, but if you think that will be the result then post it. We all want better answers.
- **Related, not-required (ask in comments):** If it's something you want to know, but don't feel it's big enough for it's own question, yet still different enough that the answer doesn't improve/clarify the true answer to the question, just ask it in comments to the accepted answer/question. If it's a short answer to a simple question, it should be short enough for people to answer in the comments. If it turns out that it should be part of the official answer, request that the author consider making an edit to the accepted answer. If it turns out to be too big a question for the comments and too different of a question for the original post, then consider asking it as a separate question.

Comment: Yes I think your point #2 is a very common use-case for "bonus questions". Whether or not answers have already been made, the OP may be attempting to narrow down what the point of confusion is, by asking a similar (but different) question as a followup. A perfect answer to the original question may need to provide clarity over why the answer is/isn't valid in the followup circumstance.

Answer (score 8):

No, it is not OK. A bonus question implies that it is an extra question, and therefore it needs to be asked in separate question. Feel free to link between those questions. Also, 'bonus' implies that you get an (extra) reward, which isn't actually the case.

When confronted with questions that have a 'bonus question', I usually consider them 'too broad' and will vote as such, or at minimum leave a comment that the 'bonus question' should be moved to its own question, or that the question needs to be edited to make it an integral part of the question.

Comment: If it is evidently best as a separate question, and it has not attracted answers already, I will edit "bonus questions" out. Posters usually prefer this than a close vote, since they can sometimes be difficult to get out of.

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing wrong with saying:

> I'd really love to do this without introducing additional dependencies.

Or, possibly:

> Big bonus if someone can do this without resorting to type-punned pointers, I'm going to need to make this build on a strict platform.

It's like someone saying:

> *I have a long list of constraints, but if you can help me get 2/3 of the way there, I'm pretty sure I can figure out the rest of it on my own. But, I'm going to let you know what else I'm dealing with, in hopes that you can help me get a little farther. Still, I'm  totally happy with just a push in the right direction.*

I don't see anything particularly wrong with that, in fact I find the clear explanation of goals and willingness to work toward them encouraging. Encouraging answers with more depth by providing some cues as to what would be most helpful is definitely not a bad thing.

The only advice I'd give is try to avoid writing *for* the check mark, write for your future self instead. *What do I know about this that I might forget someday?* *What does the 'bonus' part make me want to write about?* Those are good questions to ask yourself, and a great way to either get the check mark or outscore the answer that did.

The only potential problem here is like treating the question as a short order cook would treat your lunch order - *hey, I gave you exactly what you asked for, where's my reward??* - Avoid that.

Instead, try: *I hear you like mayo, pickles and celery. Prepare yourself, for I am cooking, and you're about to love how capers goes with that.*

> Bonus: Can you help me get my dog to speak Latin?

... No.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If the two questions are closely-related aspects of the one core question, then it's probably okay, since future readers are likely to benefit from an answer that addresses both aspects.

However, if the second question is specific to the OP's situation in a way that makes it relatively independent of the primary question then adding that second question makes the question as a whole *less* useful to future readers. That's just a simple matter of probability.

If *p* is the probability that the first question is relevant to a given reader, and *q* is the probability that the second question is relevant to that reader, then if the two questions are relatively independent the probability that combined pair of questions is relevant is *pq*. So even if each of those questions is useful to 1 reader in 10, the pair of questions is useful to 1 reader in 100; a triplet of such questions would be useful to 1 in a 1000. Etc. And that's a major reason why the Stack Exchange policy discouraging people from bundling totally unrelated questions together is so important.

FWIW, I made a similar remark in response to [Close the loop on “Too Broad”; make the close reason's actual intent reflected in its message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323721/close-the-loop-on-too-broad-make-the-close-reasons-actual-intent-reflected-i) but as it was just a comment I didn't go into the mathematical details.

Answer (score -1):

I think in some cases it is fine.

Especially if the bonus question wouldn't make a good standalone question or potentially even survive as a standalone question without being closed.

e.g. standalone questions asking "why?" about implementation decisions often receive short shrift. The answer may not be known to anyone except the original designers but alternatively might be both available and informative.

A silly example might be

> I am trying to wibble the foo I tried `foo.Wibble()` but that gave me
> an error that the foo cannot be wibbled on Tuesdays.
>
> **Primary Question:** How can I work around this issue and achieve objective X?
>
> **Bonus Question:** If anyone can incorporate into their answer an explanation of why this Tuesday restriction is in place I'd be interested to know.